# Is it possible to process content plugins before returning articles in Web Services?

Tags: joomla-5.x, restful-api, content-plugin

Imagine a have a list of content plugins installed on joomla like:

- Snippets
- LoadModule
- etc...

I have an article with the following content:

```
<p>{snippet id="1"} {loadmoduleid 1}</p>
```

When I call a webservice to get an article
`localhost/joomla/api/index.php/v1/content/articles/1`:

I get the following response:

```
{
  "text": "<p>{snippet id=\"1\"} {loadmoduleid 1}<\/p>",
}
```

Is it possible to process plugins before getting this response?

Answer (score 0):

Yes it can be one but you might need to adapt an existing content plugin or if it is 3rd party extension you might ask them to write a plugin for webservices.

Looking at the code for `../components/com_content` there are numerous places where plugins are triggered for events called `onContentPrepare`, `onContentAfterTitle` and the two that are most likely events for the plugins you might be comparing with in the 'site'(frontend) environment `onContentBeforeDisplay` & `onContentAfterDisplay`.

However in `../api/com_content`, that is the code of com_content used by Webservices, the only event triggered is `onContentPrepare` as there really is no use for a Title and Display of the component for the screen.

The above example is for the core com_content component however the same structure would apply to any 3rd party component you might be trying to alter the contents of that will require analysis of the 3rd party components code to find what it triggers in its `/api/...` directory.

Therefore any plugin you want to execute or write for Webservices has to use `onContentPrepare` for com_content or any other event triggered by the `/api/com_othercomponent`  and it must be eligible to execute in the 'api' environment rather than usual 'site'(front-end) and 'admin'(back-end) environments of normal content plugins.

Comment: Is it feasible to develop a custom plugin capable of processing all installed content plugins, by calling their implementation, solely during Web Services API calls? This functionality would be implemented within the onContentPrepare event.

Comment: It would be feasible but perhaps not practical as it might come down to each plugin being called as to whether you are going to get the response you want. For example if you manage to call an onBeforeDisplay or an onContentPrepare but the plugin itself checks its environment and only runs in 'site' then it will exit without running. You would need to understand each plugin on your instance and confirm it is doing what you expect.